# Solr - Search words within a string

Tags: string, text, solr

I have a field containing a lot of words, for example:

"hello my name is Nicole and I am working with Solr"

and I need Solr to return this document if I search for this words (note that the word order is not as in the indexed text):

"am name with"

I am using this configuration

```
<fieldType name="propertiesField" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="-" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

and this query:

select/?q=properties_all:am-name-with&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on

when I analize it with the analyzer, those words are highlighted but no document is found when I do the search.

Thanks for your help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no good reason to use different index and query time analyzer, do not.

I would fieldType like:

```
<fieldType name="propertiesField" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Additionally set default operator as AND (schema file)

```
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>
```

Then query Solr with:

```
select/?q=properties_all:(am name with)&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on
```

Comment: Thaks!! now if I need to add a SynonymFilter only in query time.. how can I do that??

Comment: Why you want to add it only in query time? If there is a strong reason to do that, use your original field type conf (but use the same tokenizer in both) and add synonym filter after lower case

Comment: @Fuxi What if I need to implement the order also ?

Comment: If I get you correctly @er_suthar, you might be interested in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-ShingleFilter

Comment: @Fuxi I thanks for your response. I have tried to add shingle filter but could not get the desired result.  I have posted a detailed question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615687/name-search-on-solr here.
Please take a look at the question.